How to Create Repeater fields with textarea with tinymce
I want to add custom meta fields for my custom post type gd_place and I want Textarea with tinymce editor.
first time its loads fine but when I click add new button its not loading tinymce.
Now if anyone can help me about this problem that will be good for me.
add_action('admin_init', 'gpm_add_meta_boxes', 2);

function gpm_add_meta_boxes()
{
    add_meta_box('gd_place', 'Paper Publication Information', 'Repeatable_meta_box_display', 'paper_publication', 'normal', 'default');
}

function Repeatable_meta_box_display()
{
    global $post;
    $gpminvoice_group = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ra_publications', true);
    wp_nonce_field('gpm_repeatable_meta_box_nonce', 'gpm_repeatable_meta_box_nonce');
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $('#add-row').on('click', function() {
                var row = $('.empty-row.screen-reader-text').clone(true);
                row.removeClass('empty-row screen-reader-text');
                row.insertBefore('#repeatable-fieldset-one tbody>tr:last');
                return false;
            });

            $('.remove-row').on('click', function() {
                $(this).parents('tr').remove();
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
    <table id="repeatable-fieldset-one" width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <?php
            $publications = array('deccan-herald' => "Deccan Herald", 'kannada-prabha' => "Kannada Prabha", "times-now" => "Times Now", "vijayavani" => "Vijayavani");

            if ($gpminvoice_group) :
                foreach ($gpminvoice_group as $field) {
            ?>
                    <tr>
                        
                        <td width="70%">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter article url" name="publicationUrl[]" value="<?php if ($field['publicationUrl'] != '') echo esc_attr($field['publicationUrl']); ?>" />
                        </td>
                        <td width="15%"><a class="button remove-row" href="#1">Remove</a></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                }
            else :
                // show a blank one
                ?>
                <tr>
                   
                    <td>
                      
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter article url" name="publicationUrl[]" />
                    </td>
                    <td><a class="button  cmb-remove-row-button button-disabled" href="#">Remove</a></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif; ?>

           
            <tr class="empty-row screen-reader-text">              
                <td><a class="button remove-row" href="#">Remove</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <p><a id="add-row" class="button" href="#">Add another</a></p>
<?php
}

